# Any Ubuntu version don't boot

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, lts

---

Any Ubuntu version don't boot. I tried dvd's with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, 32 bit; 11.04 64 bit, 32 bit. I tried also USB drive with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit, 32 bit. There was no respond with dvd's at all, with USB there was written "SYSLINUX" on a black screen and nothing happen. I have my HDD prepared with ext3 and linux-swap partitions.

I'm using Acer Aspire 4920.
Intel Core 2 Duo 1.66GHz
2 GB ram

I tried from Windows XP as well as Windows 7.
My first try was to install Ubuntu on the blanc HHD.

I really want to use Ubuntu instead of any Windows, but I had tried so many things and I can't get it to even boot.

Can anybody help me install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Best regards 
Matt

Comment: What disk burning software are you using? If you're trying to make a bootable CD from Windows I don't think it will work. You'll want a CD burning program like Roxio or Nero. If you don't have one of those, download.com has one called Deepburner that has worked for me.

Comment: I burned dvd with Deepburner, and black screen booted instead of Windows. Nothing happen after black screen, Ubuntu didn't boot. I tried also USB prepared with Unetbootin, in this case USB booted but there was no ubuntu over there at all, only default choice. Choosing default option cause laptop to reboot again and place it in very same place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assure that your dvd drive is on top priority of your boot device list in your bios. In most cases you can configure that by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> at boot time or <kbd>F12</kbd> for temporally setting. But depends on your Bios...

You checked that already?

Comment: Sure I did. I changed BIOS top priority to dvd drive in case of dvd's and to USB drive in case of USB drive. It's just don't want to start :(

Answer (score 0):

A couple of trouble shooting steps would be to:

1. Make sure you use a proper disk burning software. Examples: Roxio, Nero, Deepburner.
   -Also, be sure that it is set to "Burn ISO image" and not a "Data" CD.
2. Be sure your BIOs is set to "Boot to CD" first. Or use the interupt keys to get to the boot menu for your PC, and select CD.

Comment: 1. I have additional question. If you put Ubuntu dvd while operating windows will it open it self with auto start as windows does? Those dvd's with Ubuntu I have right now are just opened by windows auto start as a window, but I don't have any new window saying "do you want to install ubuntu?". 2. I did all that.